# Update column1 with identical column2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this:

```
ID    Num
1     KP2
2     KP3
3     KP2
4     KP3
5     KP3
```

I need to get this:

```
   ID    Num
    1     KP2
    2     KP3
    1     KP2
    2     KP3
    2     KP3
```

I tried this:

```
  UPDATE t
  SET ID = t2.ID
  FROM table t JOIN table t2 ON t.Num = t2.Num
```

This does not work though. Nothing is changes It says that rows were updated, but IDS are still the same.

Comment: What error are you getting? A key error perhaps? I also expect that you might want a more specific join.

Comment: For future reference; explain the problem fully, don't make people read and re-read your examples in order to spot what you want and the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
UPDATE t
SET ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM t AS t2 WHERE t.Num = t2.Num)
```

Having said that, the name "ID" sort of suggests primary key. Are you *sure* this is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [SQLMenace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729568/update-column1-with-identical-column2/7729642#7729642) but avoiding the `JOIN`

```
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                dense_rank() OVER(ORDER BY num) AS Number
         FROM  YourTable)
UPDATE T
SET    id = Number
```

Answer (score 0):

One way by using a windowing function

```
UPDATE t
 SET t.id =x.number
 FROM (SELECT num,dense_rank() OVER(ORDER BY num) AS Number
 FROM table) x
 JOIN table t ON t.num = x.num
```

example you can run

```
CREATE TABLE #test (id INT, num VARCHAR(100))
INSERT #test VALUES(1,'KP2')
INSERT #test VALUES(2,'KP3')
INSERT #test VALUES(3,'KP2')
INSERT #test VALUES(4,'KP3')
INSERT #test VALUES(5,'KP3')



 UPDATE t
 SET t.id =x.number
 FROM (SELECT num,dense_rank() OVER(ORDER BY num) AS Number
 FROM #test) x
 JOIN #test t ON t.num = x.num

 SELECT * FROM #test



1   KP2
2   KP3
1   KP2
2   KP3
2   KP3
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 UPDATE t   
 SET ID = t2.ID   
 FROM table t 
 JOIN (select min(ID), num from table group by num)t2 
    ON t.Num = t2.Num
```